# What's next after 2010 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, iis

I've done a attach upgrade from a 2007 db to 2010 following the [MS guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx#AddDB) and all went ok.

However, I have no idea what to do next.  When I navigate to the root web page I just get the default site, not the new one I just attached.

So, I remove the previous database from central admin and then I get a HTTP 404 error page only.

Do i need to do something in IIS or have I missed something in the upgrade or something?  BTW, as you can probably tell I'm a complete newbie at all of this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reattach the upgraded database. Since the default site was already there when you attached it, it didn't properly find your site collections. Now that the default site collection is gone you should be ok if you reattach (assuming nothing else has gone wrong and all other steps have been completed).

Comment: Hi, thanks i tried that and it says 'The attach operation cannot continue because another object in this farm already contains the same ID.'

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear - by reattach I mean remove it from the farm, and then attach it again. Sounds like you missed the remove step. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, still no good.  reattached and still the same.  It's like I'm missing a step to tell it (IIS maybe) where to find the default page when i navigate to [http]://myserver

Comment: Does central admin say that the web application has site collections?

Comment: Hmmm, good point.  No it doesn't.  It says Number of site collection...0

Comment: Feel free to meet me in chat - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint